# Comparing emmeans posteriors from a Bayesian linear mixed effects model

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, linear-model

I've come quite a long way with Bayesian (G)LMMs recently, but sometimes there are things you can't quite google. Fortunately, someone was very kind to integrate emmeans with brms (a package for easy conversion of classic (g)lm(er) R syntax to apply to Bayesian models of the same kind). This makes much of my work much easier in this arena.

My question is probably more methodological than implementational. Assume I have a fairly simple Bayesian linear model, setup with the formula `error ~ condition*round`. Assume `error` is continuous, and `condition` has two levels (group A and group B) and `round` has two levels (pre-training and post-training).

If I draw posteriors for the estimated marginal means (EMMs) over the combination of `condition` and `round`, is it then appropriate to perform further comparison between these distributions? So assume my analyses thus far suggest there's an interaction where group A improves from pre- to post-training, but group B does not. Is it appropriate in this case to quantify a difference distribution, comparing the group A pre-training EMM posterior minus the group A post-training EMM posterior, and the same comparison for group B? Is it further appropriate to quantify the extent to which these difference distributions might differ from a null value, for example using a ROPE around that null?

Such an analysis seems straightforward to me, and, in computing this analysis, the results agree with other analyses (e.g. the results generally accord with simply calculating the overlap coefficient between group A pre-training and group A post-training EMMs, but I want something a bit more quantitative than just the overlap coefficient). I just am not quite well-versed enough in some of these Bayesian methods to know if I'm secretly violating some assumptions about this model or these quantification techniques.

Comment: I don't see why not. The `contrast` function may be useful in constructing these samples.

Answer (score 2):

Nice question! Since I am a frequentist and not a Bayesian, I will state the linear model you are fitting below:

```
error = beta0 + beta1*conditionB + beta2*roundPost +    
        beta3*conditionB:roundPost + error_term
```

where:

a) conditionB is a dummy variable defined as 1 if condition = Group B and 0 if condition = Group A;

b) roundPost is a dummy variable defined as 1 if round = Post and 0 if round = Pre;

c) error_term is a random error term assumed to be normally distributed with mean 0 and unknown variance $\sigma^2$.

Note that the model formulation is the same, regardless of what statistical framework you will use to fit the model: frequentist or Bayesian.

The above model is in effect a collection of 4 sub-models corresponding to all possible combinations of levels/categories of your condition and round variables represented in your data.

**Submodel 1 [condition = Group A; round = Pre]**

```
error = beta0 + error_term
```

**Submodel 2 [condition = Group A; round = Post]**

```
error = beta0 + beta2 + error_term
```

**Submodel 3 [condition = Group B; round = Pre]**

```
error = beta0 + beta1 + error_term
```

**Submodel 4 [condition = Group B; round = Post]**

```
error = beta0 + beta1 + beta2 + beta3 + beta4 + error_term
```

These submodels suggest that the (true) mean value of the error response is:

```
beta0 for condition = Group A and round = Pre;

beta0 + beta2 for condition = Group A and round = Post;

beta0 + beta1 for condition = Group B and round = Pre;

beta0 + beta1 + beta2 + beta3 for condition = Group B and round = Post.
```

So you can define the effect of round on error for condition A as the difference of the means (beta0 + beta2) - beta0, which equals beta2.

Further, you can define the effect of round on error for condition B as the difference of the means (beta0 + beta1 + beta2 + beta4) - (beta0 + beta1), which equals beta2 + beta3.

The quantities beta2 and beta2 + beta3 represent the simple effects of round for conditions A and B and can be estimated using the contrast() function, as suggested by Russ in his comment. Given a linear regression model, a contrast is a linear combination of (true) regression coefficients which allows you to compare mean values of your response variable across conditions of interest.